# Creating a dynamic SVG React component using createElement is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg

In my React application, I'm attempting to build an Icon Component `FontIcon` which should create a `svg component` dynamically right now. The SVGs are imported here as well.

*The ideal scenario is for the svg to be displayed when a prop is used to choose an svg.*

The dynamic component (`FontIcon`) has a list of SVGs and checks to verify if the selected SVG is present. If not, a default SVG is used. Unfortunately, and I don't know why, I receive this error. The SVG component is somehow not built.

```
 <data:image/svg.... /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.
```

FontIcon.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import FasExclamationCircle from "./exclamation-circle.svg";
import FarClock from "./clock.svg";

export const iconTypes: { [key: string]: string } = {
    FarClock: FarClock,
    FasExclamationCircle: FasExclamationCircle,
};

type Props = {
    icon: string;
};

export const FontIcon: React.FC<Props> = ({ icon }) => {
    const SvgIcon = iconTypes[icon] == undefined ? FasExclamationCircle : iconTypes[icon];

    return React.createElement(SvgIcon, {
        className: "some class name",
    });
};
```

App.tsx (I am using that Component)

```
import FontIcon from "./FontIcon"

<div><FontIcon icon="FarClock"/></div>
```

p.s That is not working as well. Even if we forget the prop logic

```
import React from "react";
import FarClock from "./clock.svg";
      

export const FontIcon: React.FC = () => {
    return React.createElement(FarClock, {
        className: "some class name",
    });
};
```

Comment: No. You can use SVGs as react components

Comment: What you get from importing svg using webpack depends on the loaders

Comment: i should get a svg not a image

Comment: Your loader seems to return a string, consequently, when calling React.createElement(type, props), the type is a string (where a tag name is expected), not a React component (class/function) nor a React fragment.

Comment: Yes by why? I am doing nothing wrong here

Comment: How did you set up your loaders? Do you have a `webpack.config.js` file?

Comment: Thats the think. I am using https://nx.dev/

Comment: 1. To use a custom webpack config file for nx.dev: https://nx.dev/guides/customize-webpack  2. The way you use imports seems to match the `svgr` one in here: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-load-svg-with-react-and-webpack